# Error: "Cannot read property apply of undefined" while running gulp commands for SPFx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, gulp, gulp-trust-dev-cert

I am trying to do a sample webpart.

While running any of the below commands, it is showing the same error as shown in the image:

- gulp trust-dev-cert
- gulp serve
- gulp build

[image]

Can anyone help me on this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your probably have your project in a folder beneath it and your current directory D:\SPFXWebpart does not contain a gulpfile.

So CD into that folder and try to run your gulp task.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Above are the project files in the image. And I have gulpfile.js in same Directory[D/SPFXWebpart] and I ran the gulp command under the same directory.

Any suggestions where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling **gulp-cli** worked for me:

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```